# iOS - Sencha Touch - 2

Tags: iphone, ios, extjs, sencha-2

I am really confused between these two command.

```
sencha app build native

[INFO] Deploying your application to /path/to/www/mySenchaApp/build/package
```

what is the command is used for?

```
sencha package run packager.json
```

what is the command is used for?

Actually i am able to run my app on simulator.
But i am not able to run the same app on my device...
Actually i am not sure what command i need to use to install on my device using itunes.

```
{
    /**
     * @cfg {String} applicationName
     * @required
     * This is the name of your application, which is displayed on the device when the app is installed. On IOS, this should match
     * the name of your application in the Apple Provisioning Portal.
     */
    "applicationName":"MySenchaApp",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} applicationId
     * This is the name namespace for your application. On IOS, this should match the name of your application in the Apple Provisioning Portal.
     */
    "applicationId":"com.cc2go.keyboard",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} versionString
     * @required
     * This is the version of your application.
     */
    "versionString":"1.0",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} iconName
     * This is file name of your icon. This should be in the same directory of this configuration file.
     *
     * For iOS, please refer to their documentation about icon sizes:
     * https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html
     *
     * For Android, please refer to the Google Launcher icons guide:
     * http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html
     */
    "iconName":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} inputPath
     * @required
     * This is location of your Sencha Touch 2 application, relative to this configuration file.
     */
    "inputPath":"build/native",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} outputPath
     * @required
     * This is where the built application file with be saved.
     */
    "outputPath":"output",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} configuration
     * @required
     * This is configuration for your application. `Debug` should always be used unless you are submitting your app to an online
     * store - in which case `Release` should be specified.
     */
    "configuration":"Debug",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} platform
     * @required
     * This is the platform where you will be running your application. Available options are:
     *  - iOSSimulator
     *  - iOS
     *  - Android
     *  - AndroidEmulator
     */
    "platform":"iOS",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} deviceType
     * @required
     * This is device type that your application will be running on.
     *
     * If you are developing for Android, this is not necessary.
     *
     * Available options are:
     *  - iPhone
     *  - iPad
     *  - Universal
     */
    "deviceType":"iPhone",



    /**
     * @cfg {String} certificatePath
     * This is the location of your certificate.
     * This is required when you are developing for Android or you are developing on Windows.
     */
     "certificatePath":"/path/to/Certificates.p12",

         "provisionProfile":"/path/to/cc2gokeyboard(3).mobileprovision",


    /**
     * @cfg {String} certificateAlias
     * This is the name of your certificate.
     *
     * IF you do not specify this on OSX, we will try and automatically find the certificate for you using the applicationId.
     *
     * This can be just a simple matcher. For example, if your certificate name is "iPhone Developer: Robert Dougan (ABCDEFGHIJ)", you
     * can just put "iPhone Developer".
     *
     * When using a certificatePath on Windows, you do not need to specify this.
     */
"certificateAlias":"iPhone Developer: First Last (EWEWNP4AYU)",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} sdkPath
     * This is the path to the Android SDK, if you are developing an Android application.
     */
    "sdkPath":"/path/to/android-sdk",

    /**
     * @cfg  androidAPILevel
     * This is android API level, the version of Android SDK to use, you can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html.
     * Be sure to install corresponding platform API in android SDK manager (android_sdk/tools/android)
     */
    "androidAPILevel":"15",

    /**
     * @cfg  orientations
     * @required
     * This is orientations that this application can run.
     */
    "orientations": [
        "portrait",
        "landscapeLeft",
        "landscapeRight",
        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

please let me know